# If neural networks are deterministic once trained how are generative able to generate different responses to inputs?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-models

Once training is finished and a neural network is in inference mode, its outputs will be deterministic, i.e. the weights have been fixed. How is it then that generative models are able to generate non-deterministic outputs?

Comment: random inputs; maybe we can be more precise if you tell us what generative models in particular you're interested in

Comment: Any of the NLP (Generative Pre-Trained i.e. ChatGPT) or the text-to-image ones (MidJourney, Stable Diffusion, Dalle-2)

Comment: see https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/32477/21542, https://keras.io/examples/generative/text_generation_with_miniature_gpt/

Comment: Thanks, maybe ai.stackexchange.com was a more fitting place for this conversation